# Add trailing slash and remove .php extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to add trailing slash because i have some pages in folder and others not so it looks like:
http://localhost/mysite/about
http://localhost/mysite/gallery/
I want to unify it.
I have already deleted the .php file extension.
But if I try to add a trailing slash, I get a error 500.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

How to remove a php file extension and add a trailing slash at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the trailing slash optional in your regex pattern. Replace your last line with the following

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: It gives nothing. Still some sites don't have trailing slash and if i type it to the end of URL i got error 500

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: Try relplacing your secon RewriteCond with **RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f** to see what it yields.

Comment: It giving error 404 for sites who already don't have trailing slash

Comment: It's wired. Are you sure the htaccess you posted here is the htaccess on your server?

Comment: I'm testing it on localhost. If this works then I'll put it on a normal server.  My htaccess works as you see giving me new erros